# How to make a custom nonrectangular gtklayout in GTK+3

Tags: gtk, gtk3

When using GTK+2, we can use `gtk_widget_shape_combine_mask` and `gtk_widget_input_shape_combine_mask` to make a custom nonrectangular gtklayout.

For example, in the case of a GTKLayout with a circle hole, we can see the widget bottom of the custom gtklayout through the circle hole.

With GTK+3, the `gtk_widget_shape_combine_mask` is replaced with `gtk_widget_shape_combine_region`. When using `gtk_widget_shape_combine_region` and `gtk_widget_input_shape_combine_region`, we *can't* see the widget bottom of the custom gtklayout through the circle hole.

Why?  How can we implement the nonrectangular GTKLayout in GTK+3?